# How to name perl module, SomeModule vs Some::Module

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there any preferred naming convention for perl modules?

For example, what is more common practice in perl world - `SomeModule` or `Some::Module`? Maybe there are some cases when one style is better than another?

Comment: "Avoid starting a new top-level hierarchy, especially if a suitable hierarchy already exists under which you could place your module." — http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html#What's-in-a-name%3f

Comment: https://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_namingmodules

Comment: While answers to this question are indeed *primarily opinion-based* it doesn't mean that this is a poor question. There are certain conventions, such as using `CamelCase` for package names and avoiding all lower-case identifiers, that should be followed if a module is expected to be used extensively, and there is a huge range of predefined names in CPAN that should be acknowledged and avoided as far as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at CPAN you will see that, by and large, module names are organised into top-level categories for the first segment of the name, and a distinctive name within that category for each module. For instance, the top ten categories (by distribution count) are

```
Net
App
WWW
Test
Data
Catalyst
Acme
Text
Dist
HTML
```

The second part of the name is usually either to identify it within all other modules of that category (such as `HTML::TreeBuilder`), or as a subdivision of a large category (like `Net::FTP::*` modules)

There may be a third section to the name, which represents either a component module of an overall set (for example `DBIx::Class::Relationship` and `DBIx::Class::ResultSet` ) or a separate module that has been subclassed from another (like `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`)

For too long there has been no control over the names of the modules uploaded to CPAN, and some parts of it can be a bit of a mess. However it does represent a defined and growing set of names that you should try to avoid with your own package identifiers. Your example isn't very realistic, but I would probably go with just `SomeModule`, as just inserting a pair of colons between every pair of words is definitely *not* the way to go

If you have multiple modules you can start gathering them together into categories, and it would help if you used a top-level category (like `Site` or `Company`) that avoided clashes with any CPAN modules that you could use. Examples could be `Site::Utils::Matrices` and `Site::Utils::StringProcessing`

The one major rule is that your package names should be in CamelCase, as all lower-case names are reserved for Perl pragmas

Since [stevieb's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334695/stevieb) solution has been deleted, it's worth me reposting a link to [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s excellent [***On The Naming of Modules***](https://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_namingmodules) which makes many salient points

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether or not you intend to put your module on CPAN. If you are putting it on CPAN, you should be reading [`perldoc perlmodstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html) anyway. If however you are just using the modules privately, the most relevant point is that the `::` is used to signify a directory hierarchy. Ex:

```
use lib 'my_module';
use Some::Module;
```

This loads a module named "Module.pm" in a folder called "Some", in the directory "my_module".

This is not to be confused with package names, which often also use `::`. With package names, `::` is usually used to designate conceptual hierarchies or relationships between packages, such as classes and sub-classes.

Comment: I think it's unwise to name your module lazily because you are "sure" that it will never make its way to CPAN. Temporary code has a habit of becoming permanent code, and any module should at least fall in with the broad scheme of CPAN naming if only to avoid clashing with it